# Book whose chapters possibly use different macros

Tags: macros, book-design

We proposed an edited book, where each chapter is written by a different author.
My doubt is: can each author uses his own set of macros (e.g. to define symbols) or this can create problems when we will put together the chapters is a single document?

Thanks!

Comment: If the authors define new macros, this is not a problem, as long as they use different macro names. If the use the same macro names, there could be problems, but these should be solvable. Problematic would be, if they use different packages. Because some package combinations are problematic, for example if the packages load different font packages, at least if they define macros with the same names.

Comment: That’s easy to accomplish. Simply have different authors write different files, and define the macros inside the files. Then use `\include{<file name>}`. Alternatively, if you don’t want each chapter to start a new page (which `\include` does), use `\input{<file name>}`, and begin each file with `\begingroup` and end it with `\endgroup`.

Comment: @Gaussler you are forgetting that commands can wander in the document, e.g. if they are used in sectioning titles and go in the table of contents, or if you want to create an index or a glossary or a bibliography. Chapters in a book are rarely so independant that you can completly ignore what happens in the other chapters or the preamble of the book.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fair point. I guess the solution is to just do your best to avoid using macros in headings etc.